# Migrate my test utils from React Router V5 to V6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am in the process of migrating my project to React V6 router but I have a problem in my test utility function. When I run my test all my expectation fails because jest can't see the object. Has anyone ever encountered this error during this migration or know what is going on?

Thank you in advance

My TestUtils file :

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react'

import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next'
import { QueryClientProvider, setLogger, QueryClient } from 'react-query'
import { Route, MemoryRouter, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'

import bo from '../../themes/bo'

import i18n from '../../../i18n'

import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

setLogger({
     log: () => console.log,
     warn: () => console.warn,
     error: () => {
        // do nothing
     }
})
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            retryDelay: 1,
            retry: 0
        }
    }
})

const AllTheProviders = ({ children, route, path }: { children?: ReactNode; route: 
string; path: string }) => {
    return (
       <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[route]}>
                    <ThemeProvider theme={bo}>
                        <ToastContainer />
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path={path} element={() => children} />
                        </Routes>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </MemoryRouter>
            </QueryClientProvider>
        </I18nextProvider>
    )
}

const customRender = (ui: ReactElement, { route = '/', path = '/' }: { route?: 
string; path?: string } = {}) =>
    render(ui, { wrapper: (props) => <AllTheProviders {...props} route={route} path=. 
{path} /> })

export * from '@testing-library/react'
export { customRender as render }
```

An example of insertion

```
 await expect(screen.findByTestId('Test#Element')).resolves.toHaveTextContent('test')
 expect(screen.queryByTestId('Test#Element')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route` component takes a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX on the `element` prop. The `AllTheProviders` component is passing a function instead.

Pass `children` prop (*typed as a `ReactNode`*) directly to `element`.

```
interface AllTheProvidersProps {
  children?: ReactNode;
  route: string;
  path: string
}

const AllTheProviders = ({ children, route, path }: AllTheProvidersProps) => {
  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[route]}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={bo}>
            <ToastContainer />
            <Routes>
              <Route path={path} element={children} />
            </Routes>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used testing-library, but it looks like the `wrapper` option of the `render` function passes its contents through the `children` prop.  If you were to rename it to `element` you would have to change the `wrapper` portion (`wrapper: (props) => <AllTheProviders {...props} element={props.children} ...`) so I would not recommend that.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Yeah, I think you're correct and I agree. It's just all less confusing with *not* renaming that prop. Removing the last half.

Comment: I think you may need to refine the type of the `children` as well?  From `ReactNode` to `JSX.Element`?  But that's based on memory and I don't have time to fact-check this right now :x

Comment: @LindaPaiste The `Route` component's `element` prop takes a `ReactNode`. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration Now if that meshes well with the wrapper's typing I'm not immediately sure of off the top of my head. You have more familiarity with TS than I do so I'm open to edits.

Comment: ah looks like it's good then.  I was thinking that the `element` needed to be a `JSX.Element` type but that's not the case [anymore](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/eb90945c783596736dccead9bd861f2fb6157f51/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L200).